# Safari Won't Show BG on the body without a html background color set

Tags: safari, cross-browser, background-image

Maybe someone out there can fill me in on whether I've encountered an odd edge case Safari bug or there was something that I missed in my CSS.

Basically, the landing page of my site (http://www.seanmichael.me/test/kodiak/) is not showing the set background (it's just showing a white background) only in Safari (6.0.5).  I was surprised by this because I have used similar full-page background images with this type of css and never encountered this issue.  The code is set on the body element as seen below:

```
body {
    background: url("img/landing-bg.jpg") #2c5277 no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I linted my css and had no errors, so I spent substantial time messing around with the CSS in dev tools to find a solution.  Oddly enough, the edit that fixed my issue was setting a background-color property on the html element.  I'm happy it works, but am still confused as to why this might happen.  Please let me know if you have an explanation.

Thank You,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having the same issue occur on another client site, I was able to figure out what the issue is.  I'm still not sure if this is a bug in Safari, but the problem is as follows:

When using the _'s (underscores) WordPress starter theme and Modernizr together, the default css in the theme is putting a clearfix on the html element itself (not on purpose).  For some reason setting the pseudo elements (before and after) of the html element in Safari to display table causes the html element itself to overlay everything on the page (which is set to white by default).  You can check out the ticket here https://github.com/Automattic/_s/issues/212 on the github page for the _'s theme.